# Looking for Java Code Analyses Framework

Tags: java, eclipse, frameworks, code-analysis

I am looking for a code analyses framework in Java for Java. 
I want to make a plugin for another very good open source project.

All I search for is a framework that reads a java file and returns a model of all objects, functions... used in the java class. (Like Eclipse Outline)

I already googled but, i couldn't find something useful.

Comment: So something that will generate a dependency graph between Objects?

Comment: I want to make a Java2UML Plugin for Umlet. Thats what i want to do with that framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is basically just a parser (you do not need code analytics per se, just an intermediary format suitable for your need). Something simple like http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser could already fit your need. If you want something a little more complete, take a look at [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/). It is a generic parser but the default implementation is in Java, and the [Java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) written for it is very good (and written by Antlr implementers).